Can I use `NotNullWhen(true)` and the ??-operator to chain out variables?
I have multiple methods that have the following signature
public static bool IsThisTrueN([NotNullWhen(true)] int? n)

and I'd like to use them like this:
var result = IsThisTrue1(out var n1) || IsThisTrue2(out var n2);
var n = n1 ?? n2;

The compiler is complaining that n2 is an unassigned local variable, but it's only unassigned if IsThisTrue1 returns true as the boolean expression then short circuits and IsThisTrue2 is not executed. But then it's guaranteed that n1 is not null and the ??-operator chooses n1.
Can I get this code running somehow in a similarly concise form or do I need to expand it? Can I tell the compiler "shut up, I know what I'm doing"?
Or am I not knowing what I'm doing and there is a serious flaw in this that would actually allow an unassigned variable to be assigned to n?

If I am not mistaken, this is just an edgecase that hasn't been implemented support for. The expressionn1 ?? n2 needs to have both variables fully assigned. I am guessing this is either something they never thought of, or just a case of not being valuable enough to implement. In my opinion, your best option is either to refactor the code to circumvent this issue, or use | instead of ||.

Interesting. I will go with refactoring then, since there are more than 2 methods and I really don't need to run them all, otherwise | was a nice suggestion.

A second comment. These attributes and the nullability syntax are not supposed to be used as guarantees, they're hints to the compiler and the programmer, but you can in fact store null in that variable, and still return true: n = null!; return true;, notice the exclamation mark. Since this is allowed, though stupid, the compiler cannot guarantee that the left branch is taken in that expression.
